# How do you calculate memory usage from the "/proc/[pid]/status" folder for a process in C?

Tags: c, memory-management

I know there are already stack overflow questions on this, and while I've read a few, I still don't quite understand how to make the calculation for memory usage for a C process.

I read multiple stack overflow questions on the topic:

**[1]** [How to measure actual memory usage of an application or process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/131303/how-to-measure-actual-memory-usage-of-an-application-or-process)

**[2]** [Memory usage of current process in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1558402/memory-usage-of-current-process-in-c)

**[3]** [Monitor memory usage of child process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2754237/monitor-memory-usage-of-child-process)

I also read these links:

**[1]** https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-simplest-and-most-accurate-way-to-measure-the-memory-used-by-a-program-in-a-programming-contest-environment

**[2]** https://locklessinc.com/articles/memory_usage/

From this, I gathered the following points:

- I can't just use `VMSize`, as this is is the **total** amount of virtual memory allocated to the process/program. The program may not use all of it. Is this a correct assumption?
- Since a program/process consists of the stack + heap + shared libraries + code segments, the calculation is `VMData (Data + Uninitialized Data + Heap Segments sizes) + VmStk (Stack Segment size)`. Am I correct in saying this? Do I also need to add `VmExe (Text Segment size)` and/or `VmLib (Shared Library usage size)`?
- A couple of suggestions I found somewhere was to use `getrusage()` (https://linux.die.net/man/2/getrusage), or to use `VmRSS` (which, apparently, is how much memory in RAM is occupied by the process). Are these also viable suggestions? I've noticed that using `/proc/[pid]/status` is more commonly used. Why use the latter suggestion over the former ones?

Edit: This is for a program I am writing that runs `fork()` and `exec()` to run multiple processes. I am just suppose to report memory usage statistics of each process.

Thank you!

Comment: First you need to define what you mean by "memory usage".  Physical RAM only, or ???

Comment: “there are already stack overflow questions on this, and while I've read a few” -- it would certainly be helpful to link them to the question. And, in general, as you already discovered, there is no single “memory usage” figure in a modern OS. Read-only ELF sections may be mapped to the same physical RAM, R/W data may be swapped out. If you could state your _ultimate_ problem better, i.e. _why_ do you need the number, that would be helpful: it would show _which_ of the “memory usages” is the right one for your use case.

Comment: You should begin by actually specifying what you mean the "memory usage of a process". Once you have a precise definition, finding out the corresponding value will become easy and you will wonder what was it that you thought was hard.

Comment: @Chris Dodd @kkm @AlexP I believe what is being asked of me is how much memory is being used by a process, when I check on said process's statistics in the `/proc/[pid]/status` folder. I've also linked the stack overflow questions I looked at previously (edited above), but I mostly looked at the two other links I listed above.

Comment: Those links tell you how to see how much of different classes of memory you are using.  So the question becomes, which classes of memory do you care about?